# Ruby switch, show only first and last

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, nokogiri

I'm scraping a webpage with nokogiri like so:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read(html))    
doc.each do |node|
  case node.name
  when 'h1'
    Puts node.text
  when 'h2'
    puts node.text
  when 'h3'
    puts node.text
  when 'h4'
    puts node.text
  when 'h5'
    puts node.text
  end
end
```

There are many h5's. I don't want to list them all, but to group them together and show only the first and last one below their respective h4.

Comment: What's the html to get an idea, and what do you really want?

Comment: You can grab what you want with a single XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a flag to detect if it the first `h5` entry.
If it is the first, you print the text. And you store the text in a variable to use it later.

If the level resets from h5 you have to write the last node text.

In the end you have to write the last node text.

Something like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read(html))    
first_flag = true
last_h5 = nil
doc.each do |node|
  #there was a h5 and now we have new version
  if first_flag == false and  node.name != 'h5'
    puts last_h5    
    first_flag = true
  end
  case node.name
  when 'h1'
    puts node.text
  when 'h2'
    puts node.text
  when 'h3'
    puts node.text
  when 'h4'
    puts node.text
  when 'h5'
    puts node.text if first_flag 
    first_flag = false
    last_h5 = node.text 
  end    
end

  #Write the last entry
  if first_flag == false and last_h5
    puts last_h5 
  end
```

This code would repeat the h5-text if there would be only one. But from your description this is not the case in your data.

Disclaimer: Untested code, the test html is missing ;)

---

If you replace the boolean flag with a counter, then you can catch also the the edge case with one h5-node.

Example:

```
h5_count = 0
last_h5 = nil
doc.each do |node|
  #there was a h5 and now we have new version
  if h5_count > 1 and  node.name != 'h5'
    puts last_h5    
    h5_count = 0
  end
  case node.name
  when 'h1'
    puts node.text
  when 'h2'
    puts node.text
  when 'h3'
    puts node.text
  when 'h4'
    puts node.text
  when 'h5'
    puts node.text if h5_count == 0
    h5_count += 1
    last_h5 = node.text 
  end    
end

  #Write the last entry
  if h5_count > 1
    puts last_h5    
  end
```

Comment: I suggest `when 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4'` (followed by `puts node.text`).

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: _This code would repeat the h5-text if there would be only one. But from your description this is not the case in your data._ - The question explicitly don't has this edge case. But you are right. This ould be catched by an additional check. (You could use a counter instead the boolean flag).

Comment: @knut Oops, I had overlooked that part of your answer. But I don't think the question rules this case out. In fact, the OP had temporarily added the URL to the question and if I'm not mistaken, single-h5 sections do exist on that page.

Comment: @knut Your added version is buggy, it misses the `2.1` in my test: https://ideone.com/zE5zgf

Comment: I'd say the `2.1` gets missed because of this `puts node.text if h5_count == 0`